# simple select query optimise

Tags: mysql, sql, select, query-optimization

I have a table defined as follows:

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cards` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `WorkerID` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `pic` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `expDate` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `reminderSent` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `regNum` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `cardType` varchar(200) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=92 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


ALTER TABLE `cards`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`), ADD KEY `cardsWorkerID_idx` (`WorkerID`);
```

But running:

```
explain
SELECT pic, expDate, Name, ID, cardType, regNum FROM cards WHERE workerID= 18
```

tells me it is scanning the entire table, even though I added an index to the workerID field. Can anyone explain what I'm missing?

Comment: It seems plausible that workerid really should be INT! Also this table definition seems incomplete.

Comment: That table 'does not compute' -- where's the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column?

Comment: What percentage of the rows have workerID=18?  If more than about 20%, the optimizer will decide that scanning the table is faster than using the index.

Comment: @Strawberry initially workerID was INT, but now the client wanted to use their own alphanumeric identifiers which they have from a previous system instead. It always be unique so that was why it was changed to varchar but the workerID being 18 in the question is a test account which was set up at the start of dev

Comment: @RickJames see comment above for reason of omission of auto increment col. At the moment the table is small because we are still in the dev phase. Any user can add as many cols as they want but in general, when used in the field no user should have more than 20% of the table

Comment: AUTO_INCREMENT=92 makes no sense then.

Comment: @Strawberry hmm I just did an export from phpmyadmin and got that code for creating the table. It must be a case where it would still autoincrement if I had an insert('', ?, ? ,?...) but my inserts now always have a value passed in for the first parameter. Is this an issue in your opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of indexes depends on the size of the data.  It also depends on the types used for the comparison.  If you have a small table, then the SQL engine might decide that a scan is more efficient than using the index.  This is particularly true if the table fits on a single data page.

In your case, though, the problem is might be data conversion.  Use the appropriate typed constant for the comparison:

```
SELECT pic, expDate, Name, ID, cardType, regNum
FROM cards
WHERE workerID = '18';
```

Comment: thank you! I overlooked the simple quotes! will accept as soon as SO allows me